# How not to display a field in form if the boolean field in database is False

Tags: django, django-forms, python-3.4, django-1.7

I would like not to display a field in form if I have a boolean field in database set to False.

Here is my code:

```
class CreateServer(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, g, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateServer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if g.boolean_clients:
            self.fields['clients'].queryset = Clients.objects.filter(game=g)
        else:
            # the fields['clients'] shouldn't be displayed in form
            pass

        ...

    class Meta:
        model = Server
        queryset = Server.objects.filter()
        fields = ['hostname', 'clients', 'map']
```

So if g.boolean_clients is true, there must be the filter, but if g.boolean_clients is false I do not want to display this field in form.

Is there any way hot to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this but try:

```
class CreateServer(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, g, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateServer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if g.boolean_clients:
            self.fields['clients'].queryset = Clients.objects.filter(game=g)
        else:
            self.fields.pop('clients')

    class Meta:
        model = Server
        queryset = Server.objects.filter()
        fields = ['hostname', 'clients', 'map']
```